# Grails 2.1.1 with JPA 1.0

Tags: grails, jpa, websphere

I would like to ask if it is possible to run Grails 2.1.1 with JPA 1.0 implementation.

I'm completely new to Grails, all I know now is that it uses Hibernate (compliant with JPA 2.0) as a persistence provider. We currently have a problem where we would like to deploy our application on a JPA 1.0 compliant server - WebSphere 7.0. This is set and can't be changed, we must use JPA 1.0 implementation (OpenJPA). So the question again is - is it possible to use grails with the provider that is in the server, or use it in a mode where jpa 1 api will be loaded by the server and the implementation will be some older hibernate ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the core hibernate plugin does not support JPA. You would need to uninstall it and use the JPA plugin instead, which seems to be compatible with JPA 1.0 and supported by SpringSource/VMWare/Pivotal - http://grails.org/plugin/gorm-jpa

Comment: Understand. Thank you very much.